# How can we compare ActionTimestamp and Posteventtimestamp in Java and how to update actiontimestamp to currentTimestamp

Tags: java, timestamp, updates, datetimeformatter, offsetdatetime

How can I compare this timestamp format "20220708T0000Z" with current time and how can we update this timestamp to current time in same format in java, I have tried DateTimeFormatter and OffsetDateTime but both are not worked for me. Please help me.
Here I am sharing my code:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter =       
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ");


postEventInfoList.stream()
            .filter
                    (e -> e.getPostEventTimestamp() == null ||
                            ZonedDateTime.parse(e.getActionTimestamp(), 
        [1]formatter).isAfter(ZonedDateTime.parse(e.getPostEventTimestamp(), formatter)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());


private void updatePostEventTimestamp(List<PostEventEntity> postEventInfoList) {
    ZonedDateTime timestamp = ZonedDateTime.now();
    
    postEventInfoList.forEach(pEvent -> {
        pEvent.setPostEventTimestamp(timestamp.format(formatter)); 
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do not keep your timestamps in strings in `20220708T0000Z` format. Keep `Instant`  objects and compare them using their `isAfter` or `isBefore` method.